# If a graph embedded on a surface is divided by a curve into a right and left that do not intersect can it be embedded on a surface of smaller genus?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, surfaces, genus

Suppose we have a graph $G$ embedded on a (smooth, orientable etc)  surface $Q$.  Suppose there is a cycle $C$ of $G$ such that

1. $C$ does not separate our surface $Q$ into two connected regions and there is no edge between vertices of $V(C)$ that are not part of the cycle $C$.
2. We define a "left" and "right" of  $C$ in a local neighborhood of $C$ on $Q$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4270549/how-to-define-thickening-and-right-left-neighbourhood-of-a-curve-reference-req
3. For  each connected component $K$ of $G \backslash C$  if there is an edge $e$ from $K$ to $C$, such that $e$ intersects the left (resp. right) of $C$ say that $K$ is left (resp. right) of $C$.
   Each component $K$ of  $G \backslash C$ is either left of $C$ (exclusive or) or right of $C$ (not both).

Cycle C in blue, rest of graph G in red,  yellow shaded nodes consist of the graph intersecting the left of C and gray shaded nodes the right.  Note there is no path in G from a gray vertex to a yellow vertex that does not intersect the cycle C.  One can see the graph G is planar as it does not use the "handle" of the torus

[image]

Can we say that $G$ is embeddable on a surface of smaller genus?

We assume all surfaces are smooth all edges of $G$ are piecewise smooth surfaces.
Also if anyone knows how to formulate this to avoid graph theory feel free to express your ideas.

Comment: If I understood the question, the curve C is embedded and closed and some parallel copy of C does not intersect the graph hence we can cut the surface along this curve and reduce the genus.

Comment: @MaximPrasolov. Yes, that's what I suspect must be the case.  However, my knowledge of topology is poor and I don't know how to formally state or prove such a statement.

Comment: What do you mean by $G\setminus C$? The graph $G$ with the removed edges of $C$ or the graph $G$ with the removed vertices of $C$ and edges incident to them?

Comment: In the former case is not clear how to split the vertices of $C$ between the "left" and "right" of $C$ in its local neighbourhood on $Q$, whereas in the latter case Condition 3 seems to be always satisfiable by sufficiently small neighborhood of $C$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky  The notation  $G \backslash C$ refers to    the graph $G$  with the removed vertices of $C$  and edges incident to them.

Comment: @HaoS I don't quite understand conditions 2 and 3. Can't I always choose a small enough tubular neighborhood of $C$ so that it does not contain any other vertices of $G$, in which case condition 3 is automatically satisfied? I think that is why Alex Ravsky's [example](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1188363) below works (as a counterexample). (Added: Ok, I see that you [responded](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1188365) to that comment. Perhaps you could add that to the question, too? Thanks!)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist  Sorry  let me clarify yet  again.  For each component $K$ of $G$ \ $C$ if there is an edge e from $K$ to $C$ such that e intersects the left (resp. right) of C  we say is to the left (resp right) of C   Condition 3 should say there is no edge from any component to the left of C to any component to the right of C.

Comment: @HaoS No issues! Thanks for clarifying. I think one should be able to show, under these conditions, that the embedding of $G$ has a face that is not homeomorphic to a disc, and that will imply that an embedding into a surface of smaller genus exists.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist  Here's my intuition  consider  the surface $Q'$ obtained  by doing "surgery" along $C$  $G$ \ $C$ is partitioned into components that previously were either "left" of $C$ or  "right" of $C$.   
I think we should be able to find a closed (smooth) curve  $f$ that separates all the components left of $C$ from all the components right of $C$.  
$Q'$ \ $f$  contains two components one containing the left components of  $G$ \ $C$  and the other the right components.
In  $Q$,  all components of  $G$ \ $C$   lie in a single region.

Comment: This implies  $f$ does not separate $Q$ into two separate regions.  Then doing surgery along $Q$ yields a surface  of smaller genus.  That's the intuition but I don't know how to make this formal as I have little knowledge of topology.

Comment: @HaoS That sounds like a reasonable intuition to me, but I admit that I also do not really know enough topology (or, [surgery theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgery_theory), perhaps) to make that argument fully rigorous. I gave an argument in my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458733) below that seems (to me) to be in the same spirit, using Youngs' theorem as a black box.

Comment: I cannot understand why you call C "a cycle of G", since in the picture C is clearly *not* a cycle of G. ALSO: I do not find the word "etc." in the phrase "smooth, orientable, etc." to be at all helpful. You need to state what your assumptions are, and not use the word "etc.".

Comment: @DanielAsimov   In the picture the blue are edges between the 3 red vertices that form a cycle.  etc means  assume any reasonable conditions you need to make the statement true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A theorem due to Youngs (1963) says that any minimal genus embedding is necessarily a $2$-cell embedding, i.e., every face is homeomorphic to a disc.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction that, the given embedding of $G$ into $Q$ is a minimal genus embedding of $G$.
Let $G_L$ and $G_R$ be the unions of the left and right components, respectively, of $G - C$.

Case 1: At least one of $G_L$ or $G_R$ is empty.

- Suppose, without loss of generality, that $G_L$ is empty.
  Consider the face of $G$ that contains $C$ and intersects the left of $C$.
  By Youngs's theorem, this face must be homeomorphic to a disc.
  But, $C$ is not contractible (else it would separate the surface $Q$ into two components).
  Hence, a small leftward shift of $C$ — which will lie in the face $f$ — will also not be contractible.
  This contradicts that $f$ is homeomorphic to a disc, since a disc is simply connected.

Case 2: Both $G_L$ and $G_R$ are nonempty.

- We first show that if a face contains vertices of $G_L$ and of $C$ (resp., of $G_R$ and of $C$), then it cannot contain vertices of $G_R$ (resp, of $G_L$).
  Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there is such a face $f$ of degree $d$.
  Let $\partial f = v_0 \dotsm v_{d-1}$ be the boundary cycle of $f$, where $i \in \mathbb{Z}/d \mathbb{Z}$.
  Without loss of generality, assume that $v_0 \in C$, and $v_{d-1} \notin C$.
  Then, we can also express the boundary as $\partial f = P_1 \dotsm P_{k}$ for some $k$, where each $P_i$ is a maximal subpath of the boundary that is contained in $G_L$ or $G_R$ or $C$.
  Note that every alternate $P_i$ must be contained in $C$, by assumption 3 (in particular, $k$ is even).
  Denote by $v_L(P_i)$ and $v_R(P_i)$ the left- and right-end vertices, respectively, of the path $P_i$.

  Now, $\mathrm{Int}(f)$ intersects a small neighborhood of $v_0 = v_L(P_1)$ in either the left of $C$ or the right of $C$.
  Without loss of generality, assume that it intersects the left of $C$.
  Then, $\mathrm{Int}(f)$ also intersects the left of a small neighborhood of $v_i$, for each $v_i \in P_1$.
  Hence, $v_L(P_2)$ must belong to $G_L$, since the edge joining $v_L(P_2)$ to $v_R(P_1)$ intersects the left of $C$ near $v_R(P_1)$.
  (We can also do a similar analysis at the other end of $P_1$. So, $v_R(P_{k})$ must belong to $G_L$, since the edge joining $v_R(P_{k})$ to $v_L(P_1) = v_0$ intersects the left of $C$ near $v_0$.)

  Since $v_L(P_2)$ belongs to $G_L$, so does every vertex $v_i \in P_2$.
  Therefore, the edge joining $v_R(P_2)$ to $v_L(P_3)$ must also intersect the left of $C$ near $v_L(P_3)$.
  Otherwise, an argument as in the parenthetical remark above will show that $v_R(P_2)$ belongs to $G_R$, which is not possible.
  Thus, proceeding inductively, we conclude that if $\partial f$ contains vertices of $C$ and $G_L$, then it cannot contain any vertices of $G_R$.
- Next, we show that if there is a face of $G$ that contains vertices of $G_L$ and of $G_R$ (but not of $C$), then we again arrive at a contradiction:
  the boundary of such a face $f$ will necessarily contain more than one connected component, since there can be no edge between vertices of $G_L$ and of $G_R$.
  But, this is not possible since $f$ is homeomorphic to a disc by Youngs's theorem.
- Now, consider the subsets $Q_L$ and $Q_R$ of $Q$ obtained by taking the union of all the vertices, edges and faces induced by $G_L \cup C$ and $G_R \cup C$, respectively.
  By assumption 3, every component of $G - C$ is in $G_L$ or $G_R$, so every vertex and edge of $G$ belongs to $Q_L$ or $Q_R$.
  By the subcases eliminated above under Case 2, every face of $G$ also belongs to $Q_L$ or $Q_R$ (but not both).
  Then, $Q = Q_L \cup Q_R = (Q_L - C) \sqcup (Q_R - C) \sqcup C$.
  This means that $C$ separates $Q$ into two components, which contradicts assumption 1.

###### References

*Youngs, J. W. T.*, Minimal imbeddings and the genus of a graph, J. Math. Mech. 12, 303–315 (1963). [Zbl 0109.41701](https://zbmath.org/0109.41701), [Zbl 0213.26001](https://zbmath.org/0213.26001).

Comment: The If there is a face $f$ of $G$ that contains vertices of both $G_L$ and $G_R$. case is a bit more complicated because it may be the case that $f$ contains a path from $G_L$ to $G_R$ that goes through $C$, but then you can conclude that there is a closed curve consisting of a subcurve of $C$, and a curve leaving $C$ from the left and entering $C$ from the right and lies in the region bounded by $f$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @HaoS Ah yes, you are right, thank you. I will think over your argument in a while, and then add it to the answer.

Comment: Btw do you have any textbook recommendations for learning how to prove these kind of things?

Comment: @HaoS I learnt about handling embeddings of simple graphs into surfaces via combinatorial methods primarily from Ringel's book: _Ringel, Gerhard_, Map color theorem, Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften. 209. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. XII, 191 p. (1974). [Zbl 0287.05102](https://zbmath.org/0287.05102).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood the question, $G$ can be nonembeddable on a surface of smaller genus even when $C$ is a Hamiltonian cycle (so $G\setminus C$ is empty) which does not separate the surface $Q$ into two connected regions. For instance, at the picture is drawn a usual unfolding of a torus $Q$ with a graph $K_{3,3}$ drawn on in, and the edges of $C$ drawn in **bold**.

[image]

Comment: Ah sorry there should be an additional condition that there are no edges between vertices of $C$.  The idea is that it is impossible to travel from the "right" of $C$ to the left of $C$ without crossing $C$.

Comment: @HaoS OK, I'll think about this. But now it is not very clear for me how this idea is compatible with the condition that $C$ does *not* separate the surface into two connected regions.

Comment: @HaoS [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEazP.png) is a usual unfolding of a torus $Q$ with a graph $K_5$ drawn on in, and the edges of $C$ drawn in **bold**. Condition 3 seems to be satisfiable by the neighborhood of $C$ drawn in grey.

Comment: Okay sorry let me clarify yet a again.  For each component $K$ of $G$ \ $C$ if there is an edge e from $K$ to $C$ such that e intersects the left (resp. right) of C  we say is to the left (resp right) of C   Condition 3 should say there is no edge from any component to the left of C to any component to the right of C.  See picture I added.